# How binding works in function monads in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

From learn you a haskell: http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more

Monad instance for function is this:

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where  
    return x = \_ -> x  
    h >>= f = \w -> f (h w) w
```

I am having trouble understanding the output of the following:

```
import Control.Monad.Instances  

addStuff :: Int -> Int  
addStuff = do  
    a <- (*2)  
    b <- (+10)  
    return (a+b)
```

`addStuff 3` returns 19. Book says 3 gets passed as parameters to both `(*2)` `and (+10)`. How?

From `h >>= f = \w -> f (h w) w` , it seems like `(h w)` is getting bound to a or b.
So, why 6 is not being passed in (+10)?

My understanding of `f` here is that when `(*2)` is `h`, `f` is the last 2 lines of `addStuff`. When `(+10)` is `h`, `f` is the last line (in this case the return statement) of `addStuff`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us first [*desugar* the `do` block [Haskell'10 report]](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14):

```
addStuff = do
    a <- (*2)
    b <- (+10)
    return (a+b)
```

is equivalent to:

```
addStuff = (*2) >>= \a -> ((+10) >>= \b -> return (a + b))
```

The inner bind expression (`(+10) >>= \b -> return (a + b)`), can thus be converted, with the bind definition to:

```
\w -> (\b -> return (a + b)) ((+10) w) w
```

and if we substitute `return` with `const`, we thus obtain:

```
\w -> (const . (a+)) ((+10) w) w
```

We thus have a function that takes as input `w`, and then calls `const . (a+)` on `(w+10)` and `w`, so it will ignore the last `w`. Semantically it is equivalent to:

```
(a+) . (+10)
```

So now our `addStuf` is equivalent to:

```
addStuff = (*2) >>= \a -> ((a+) . (+10))
```

and if we now use the definition for the bind operator again, we see:

```
\w -> (\a -> ((a+) . (+10))) ((*2) w) w
```

or shorter:

```
\w -> (\a -> ((a+) . (+10))) (w*2) w
```

We can now substitue `a` with `(w*2)` and obtain:

```
\w -> ((w*2)+) . (+10)) w
```

So our `addStuf` is equivalent to:

```
addStuff w = (w*2) + (w+10)
```

or more simple:

```
addStuff w =  3*w + 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Haskell `do` notation is syntactic sugar for a series of `>>=` bindings; in this case, for something like this:

```
addStuff = (*2) >>= (\a -> (+10) >>= (\b -> return (a + b)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing the updated argument between the computation steps (which would thus be serving a role of a state) is the job of another monad, namely the State monad.

The function aka Reader monad is simpler than that, does less work:

```
-- (return x) w = x
-- (h >>= f)  w = f (h w) w 

(h >>= (\a ->   g >>= (\b ->   return (f a b))))   w                   
=   
       (\a ->   g >>= (\b ->   return (f a b)))  (h w)   w
= 
(g >>= (\b ->   return (f  (h w)  b)))   w
= 
       (\b ->   return (f  (h w)  b)))  (g w)   w
= 
                return (f  (h w)  (g w))        w
= 
                        f  (h w)  (g w)
```

Thus the input argument `w` is passed *unchanged* into both (by extension, all) the computation steps. Or in the specific case you ask about,

```
    liftM2 (+) ( *2) ( +10)  w 
 = 
           (+) (w*2) (w+10)
```

`liftM2` function is equivalent to the `do` block that you show,

```
liftM2 f h g =
   do {
     a <- h ;
     b <- g ;
     return (f a b) }
 =
   h >>= (\ a ->
    g >>= (\ b ->  return (f a b) ))
```

in any monad.